# How is the implication introduction used here?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I don't understand how the implication intruductions, the ones marked with the subscript $2 $ and $3 $ are used here. As I unerstand it, the implication introduction is used when we have a derivation from say $\phi $ to $\psi $, we can then discharge the assumption of $\phi $ and conclude $(\phi \to \psi )$. But here the derivation before the implication indruduction $2 $ doesn't start with $\top $, and the derivation that end in $\top $ before the implication indtroduction $3 $ does not start with $\neg \bot $. What is meant here?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step ($\rightarrow I_1$ : top left) is :

*i)* $\bot$ --- assumed

*ii)* $\bot \vdash \bot$

*iii)* $\vdash \bot \rightarrow \bot$ --- from ii) by $\rightarrow$-Introduction

> *iv)* $\vdash \lnot \bot$ --- from iii) by abbreviation : $\lnot P := P \rightarrow \bot$.

---

The second step ($\rightarrow I_2$ : bottom left) is only a "tricky" application of $\rightarrow$-Introduction : $A \vdash B \rightarrow A$.

To see that it is correct, we can use the *Hilbert-style* version of *propositional logic*.

It is a well-known fact that $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ is a *valid* logic law (in classical logic, it is a *tautology*).

Intuitively, it is so becuase, if $A$ is true, then the *conditional* $B \rightarrow A$ is also true.

In the *Hilbert-style* version of *propositional calculus* this formula is often an *axiom*.

Thus, from $\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$, if we assume $A$, then by *modus ponens* we can derive : $B \rightarrow A$.

The same fact can be "translated" into *Natural Deduction* with the possibility to "discharge" a formula $B$ whatever with an application of $\rightarrow$-Introduction :

> $$\frac{A}{B \rightarrow A}$$

Conclusion : apply it with $\lnot \bot$ as $A$ and $\top$ as $B$ to get :

> $$\frac{\lnot \bot }{\top \rightarrow \lnot \bot} (\rightarrow I_2)$$

The same for top right, with $(\rightarrow I_3)$.

---

*Note*

For an explanation, see Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/110761077X) (2013), page 22 :

> > There is a limiting case of a derivation in which an assumption $A$ is made. It is at the same time a derivation of the conclusion $A$ from the assumption $A$, as in:
> >
> > 1. $A$ : hypothesis
> > 2. $A \rightarrow A$ : 1,$\rightarrow$-I
> >
> > In terms of the derivability relation, the hypothesis on line 1 can be written as $A \vdash A$ and line 2 as $\vdash A \rightarrow A$.
> >
> > Consider as another case $\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$. Verbally, if we assume $A$, then $A$ follows under any other assumption $B$ :
> >
> > 1. $A$ : hypothesis
> > 2. $B \rightarrow A$ : 1,$\rightarrow$-I
> > 3. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ : 1–2,$\rightarrow$-I
> >
> > This does not look particularly nice: We have closed an assumption $B$ that was not made. But if we say that an assumption was used $0$ times, the thing starts looking more reasonable. [...] we can say that assumption $B$ in the derivation of $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ was used *vacuously*.

In details, we have to compare the two following derivations :

> **(A)** $\vdash A \rightarrow A$

*i)* $A$ - assumed

*ii)* $A \vdash A$

*iii)* $\vdash A \rightarrow A$ --- from ii) by $\rightarrow$-I.

> **(B)** $\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$

*i)* $A$ - assumed

*ii)* $B$ --- assumed

*iii)* $A,B \vdash A$ --- from i) and ii)

*iv)* $A \vdash (B \rightarrow A)$ --- from iii) by $\rightarrow$-I

*v)* $\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ --- from iv) by $\rightarrow$-I.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! But when you write
$$\frac{A}{B \rightarrow A}$$,

I would like to write this as 
$$\frac{A\rightarrow (A \rightarrow B) A}{B \rightarrow A}\rightarrow I$$,

how come you don't write the $A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B) $?

Comment: Do you supress it because it always is true?

Comment: @Alexander - $\frac{A→(B→A), \quad A}{B \rightarrow A}$ is correct, but it is **not** a rule. To do it you have first to prove : $\vdash A→(B→A)$; to do this, you have to use $\rightarrow$-intro from : $\frac{A}{B \rightarrow A}$ to derive : $\frac{}{A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)}$.

Comment: But I don't get $\frac{A}{B \rightarrow A}$, is this $\frac{[B \rightarrow A ]^1 A}{B \rightarrow A}\rightarrow I^1$?

Comment: @Alexander - NO (see referenced book above) : $\frac{[A]}{B \rightarrow A}$ "The first inference step is justified by the rule about sets of assumptions: $A — B = A$. There is a **vacuous discharge** of $B$ in the first instance of $\rightarrow$-intro". It is like, in *Hilbert-style* : if $\Gamma \vdash A$, then $\Gamma,B\vdash A$ (you can always add an assumption). Thus, from $A\vdash A$, we have $A,B\vdash A$, and now we use $\rightarrow$-intro : $A\vdash (B \rightarrow A)$. Only now you discharge $A$ through a new $\rightarrow$-intro to conclude : $\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$.

Comment: Ok, but what does $A-B=A $ denote?

Comment: @Alexander - It simply means that form the set $\{ A \}$ of assumptions you "remove $B$, what you get is still $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Formal way of introducing implication is first assuming $A$ then deriving some $B$ and next you introduce $A \rightarrow B$ and discharge $A$. You can assume anything you want (any $A$) but if you do not use $A$ in derivation you can take informal abbreviation by not assuming any $A$ (since you won't use it anyway) and just introducing $A \rightarrow$ at some point. You can do this because you can translate this kind of proof to correct proof in which you first assume $A$ and later discharge it.