# Is $\large \frac{\varphi}{\psi\to \varphi}$ a correct derivation using just $(\to I)$?

Tags: logic

In Dirk Van Dalen's text "Logic and Structure" third edition  (page 33) the following line is written:

> Furthermore one may apply $(\to I)$ if there is no hypothesis available for cancellation e.g.$ \large \frac{\varphi}{\psi\to \varphi} $ is a correct derivation using just $(\to I)$

I'm a little confused with this;I can't see how its a correct derivation according to the (usual) inductive definition of a derivation given in *def 1.4.1*. I wonder if this is a typo for $ \large \frac{\varphi}{\varphi\to \varphi}$ which I think is a correct derivation [with the hypothesis chosen to remain uncancelled]

Comment: No, it is correct. You can consider that $\varphi \to (\psi \to \varphi)$ is a tautology.

Comment: The issue is: we can always add "unnecessary" assumptions; see [Weakening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule). See Lemma 2.4.3. (a) page 35.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250758/what-sequent-does-this-derivation-prove)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But how to prove it from the inductive definition?

Comment: In a nutshell we have: $\varphi \vdash \varphi$ and thus $\psi, \varphi \vdash \varphi$, from which - by $(\to \text I)$ we have $\varphi \vdash \psi \to \varphi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA There is no such weakening rule given in the inductive definiition

Comment: "**Definition 2.4.2** The relation $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ between sets of propositions and propositions is defined as follows: there is a derivation with conclusion $\varphi$ and with all (uncanceled) hypotheses in $\Gamma$." Thus $\psi,\varphi \vdash \varphi$ is a derivation.

Comment: The inductive def I'm talking about are given in page 35 here  http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Ax-books/Disk_01/Dalen-Logic-and-Structure.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate question.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289794/error-in-logic-and-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{\varphi}{\psi\to\varphi}{\small({\to}\mathsf I})$ is valid.   The rule of conditional introduction allows you to discharge as many of the assumptions of the antecedent ($\psi$) that have been made; including none of them.   So it is okay that none have been assumed.   You may safely discharge all of them; which is none.

---

Since $\varphi\vdash\varphi$ is valid, $\psi,\varphi\vdash\varphi$ is too, and so you may infer $\varphi\vdash\psi\to\varphi$.

Comment: According to the book only if $\psi$ is an assumption you're allowed to discharge so how to make it an assumption using the inductive laws?

Comment: The inductive def im asking about are given in page 35 here http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Ax-books/Disk_01/Dalen-Logic-and-Structure.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289794/error-in-logic-and-structure?noredirect=1&lq=1 I summarised my confusion here

Comment: Why isn't it $\dfrac{\varphi \space \space  [\psi]}{\psi\to\varphi}$

Comment: Can you please state the implies intro rule formally?

Comment: Are the rules https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/Onderwijs/Proof_Theory_2016/handout_2.pdf given here OK ?

Comment: Why the downvote? Does my question really deserve to be downvoted?