# Fitch-style Deductive Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I am having trouble with the following question:

Give natural deduction proofs of the following formulas (from no assumptions):
$p \to p$.

Here is what I have so far:

$$\begin{array}{|l}\hline~~\begin{array}{|l}1.~p
\\\hline 2.~p
\end{array}&\raise {1ex}{\rm A\\\rm R,1}
\\n.~ p\to p &\rm I\to,1{-}2\end{array}$$

How do I proceed if I want to prove that $p\to p$ follows from the assumption $p$? I know that this question is poorly formatted, but any help would still be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Replace $n$ with $3$ and you have a proof that $p\to p$ follows from no assumptions. Thence it will follow from any assumption at all, including an assumption of $p$.

Comment: Can you make it clearer what you are asking?

Comment: Is this proof correct?

Comment: If you have a proof of something from no assumptions you can always weaken it to a proof with assumptions. Just assume some statements at the beginning and don’t do anything with them.

Comment: See he explanation in the answer to the post [How is the implication introduction used here ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938764/how-is-the-implication-introduction-used-here)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct. Here are the steps you provided in a [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) showing they are correct:

[image]

This proof checker would accept even a shorter proof:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/